# Универсальное имя символа

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    const int size = 10;

    string path = "filetext.txt";
    ofstream fout;

    fout.open("C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\filFile.txt");

    fout.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

Неправильно сформировано универсальное имя символа, в чём проблема?

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно заменить строку: fout.open("C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\filFile.txt"); на fout.open("C:\\Users\\Andrey\\Desktop\\filFile.txt");

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.